# How to validate string and convert it to a specific format python

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to create code that will take text input, eliminate all whitespace characters (left and right, not those between characters) and then validate if the string has following format: 'XXX XXX' (where X is letter or digit). If it doesn't (say that it has XXX-XXX or XXXXXX format) it would convert it to such format.

I know that I can use `strip` to remove whitespace from a string. I also know how to check the length of a string and how to convert it, but I don't know how to validate a string after using `.strip()`.

Comment: You should use regular expressions (`re`).

Comment: Please provide code examples of what you've tried. As DyZ said, you can use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regular expressions.

```
>>> import re
>>> inp.strip() 
aB8-9uG
>>> match = re.match(r"([0-9a-zA-Z]{3})(?:\-| |)([0-9a-zA-Z]{3})", _)
>>> match
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 7), match='aB8-9uG'>
>>> match.group(1) + " " + match.group(2)
aB8 9uG
```